# Runtime exception thrown while executing groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

I am a newbie to groovy scripting, I have the task to compare XML responses received from 2 endpoints. The response contents will remain same but there could be differences in the order of tags, namespace prefixes. I have researched and extracted groovy script statements and framed the script as below.

```
import java.io.File`;
import java.util.Date;
import jxl.*;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.*
import groovy.xml.*
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def xml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText( new File("D:\\GroovyTest\\responses\\getCustDetA.xml_Response.xml").getText())
def xml2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText( new File("D:\\GroovyTest\\responses\\getCustDetB.xml_Response.xml").getText() )
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true)
XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true)
def xmlDiff = new Diff(xml1,xml2)
assert xmldiff.identical()
```

When I run the script runtime exceptions occur as given below. Please help to resolve this issue or a suggestion to write it in a better way.

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor
  for: org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff(groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild,
  groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) error at line: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Diff doesn't take Groovy Slurper's NodeChild classes as constructor parameters (as it says in the exception)

As the [JavaDoc for the class shows](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Diff.html), you could just use Strings, ie:

```
String xml1 = new File("D:\GroovyTest\responses\getCustDetA.xml_Response.xml").text
String xml2 = new File("D:\\GroovyTest\\responses\\getCustDetB.xml_Response.xml").text
def xmlDiff = new Diff(xml1,xml2)
```